# Excel VBA - Optionbuttons, comboboxes and case select not communicating

Tags: excel, vba

I have in my form two comboboxes “Cb1”, "Cb2” and three optionbuttons “Op1”…“Op3”. In the form I also have a button “Btn”. When I click on the button, this is what it should appear (see code below), but in reality nothing happens. How to make this work?

```
Private Sub Btn_Click()

  Dim Output as string

Select Case Op1.Value
    Case Is = 1
       If Cb1.ListIndex = -1 Then ‘if nothing is selected
          Output = MsgBox “Select one fruit at least”
       End If

       If (Cb1.ListIndex >= 0) And (Cb2.ListCount = 0) Then ‘ if Cb1 is populated but Cb2 is not
          Output = MsgBox “There is no valid basket”
       End If

       If (Cb1.ListIndex >= 0) And (Cb2.ListCount = 1) And (Cb2.ListIndex = -1) Then ‘if Cb1 is populated and Cb2 has on item on the list but Cb2 is not selected
          Output = MsgBox “One basket is available, but not selected”
       End If

       If (Cb1.ListIndex >= 0) And (Cb2.ListCount > 1) And (Cb2.ListIndex = -1) Then ‘if Cb1 and Cb2 are populated but Cb2 is not selected
          Output = MsgBox “More than one basket is available, but none selected”
       End If

       If (Cb1.ListIndex >= 0) And (Cb2.ListCount > 0) Then ‘if Cb1 and Cb2 are populated and selected
          Select Case Cb2.Text
               Case "Basket 01"
                  Call Marry
               Case "Basket 02"
                  Call John
          Case Else
          End Select
       End If

   Case Else
End Select

Select Case Op2.Value
   Case Is = 1
       Output = MsgBox “Today it will rain”
   Case Else
End Select


Select Case Op3.Value
   Case Is = 1
       Output = MsgBox “Today it will NOT rain”
   Case Else
End Select

    If (Op1.Value=0) And (Op2.Value=0) And (Op3.Value=0) then ‘ if no optionbuttons are selected 
        Output = MsgBox “Optionbuttons are not selected yet”
    End if

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is this code placed? Sheet, module, userform?

Comment: Hi Alexis, it is placed in an userform

Comment: @LuizVaughan see answer and code in my post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to your Post (assuming you are able to populate the **ComboBoxes** and all the UserForm elements correctly in the UserForm Init/Activate).

The **OptionButton** can get a value of True/False, so there is no need to use `Select Case`, but a `If / Else`. See modified code below :

```
Private Sub Btn_Click()

Dim Output As String

If Op1.Value Then
    If Cb1.ListIndex = -1 Then ' if Nothing Is Selected
        Output = "Select one fruit at least"
        MsgBox Output
    End If

    If (Cb1.ListIndex >= 0) And (Cb2.ListCount = 0) Then ' if Cb1 is populated but Cb2 is not
        Output = "There is no valid basket"
        MsgBox Output
    End If

    If (Cb1.ListIndex >= 0) And (Cb2.ListCount = 1) And (Cb2.ListIndex = -1) Then ' if Cb1 is populated and Cb2 has on item on the list but Cb2 is not selected
        Output = "One basket is available, but not selected"
        MsgBox Output
    End If

    If (Cb1.ListIndex >= 0) And (Cb2.ListCount > 1) And (Cb2.ListIndex = -1) Then ' if Cb1 and Cb2 are populated but Cb2 is not selected
        Output = "More than one basket is available, but none selected"
        MsgBox Output
    End If

    If (Cb1.ListIndex >= 0) And (Cb2.ListCount > 0) Then ' if Cb1 and Cb2 are populated and selected

        Select Case Cb2.Text
            Case "Basket 01"
               ' Call Marry

            Case "Basket 02"
               ' Call John

            Case Else

        End Select

    End If

Else
    ' do something here...
End If


If Op2.Value Then
    Output = "Today it will rain"
    MsgBox Output
Else
   ' do something here...
End If


If Op3.Value Then
    Output = "Today it will NOT rain"
    MsgBox Output
Else
    ' do something here...
End If

If Not Op1.Value And Not Op2.Value And Not Op3.Value Then   ' if none of the Option buttons is selected
    Output = "Optionbuttons are not selected yet"
    MsgBox Output
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Your solution has worked. Kind regards !